# usage of absolute value within natural log in solution of differential equation

Tags: absolute-value, differential

y=2^x sinx
rewriting, |y|=2^x |sinx|

my questions, before taking the natural log for both sides and rearrange why do we need to rewrite using absolute value?
why this particular question need to have absolute value?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid complex numbers, the logarithm is only defined on $(0,\infty)$.  So if $y$ happens to be negative, you can't take its logarithm.
But  $|y| \ge 0$ (there is still the possibility of $0$, but maybe that's not important in this example).

Comment: thanks robert. but i still don't really get it. I foresee that even  if I get this kind of question later, I will not really know when should I use absolute value sign. Is there any indicator for me to know whether to use it or not?

Comment: You didn't say what the question was.